# What is Spring Security`secured-annotations="enabled"` analogue for Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

Consider I use Java config for spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

How can I do analogue of XML configuration

`<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation to configure that and set `securedEnabled` annotation attribute to `true`.

> [`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html)
>
> Enables Spring Security global method security similar to the
> `<global-method-security>` xml support.